# Medallion Qualification Miles vs. regular miles

Tags: loyalty-programs, delta-air-lines

I'm considering applying for a [Delta SkyMiles credit card](https://www262.americanexpress.com/dapply/web/getthecard/us/api/dal/dal-hp/ccsg-multi-lp). The Platinum card says you can get 5,000 MQMs (Medallion Qualification Miles) and up to 30,000 bonus miles. Based on the wording I think there a difference between MQMs and 'bonus miles'. Google has not helped me. 5,000 miles towards raising my status is not a big deal (looking at the card fee) but 30,000 miles towards my status is a big deal (understanding I would have to make purchases). But 30,000 miles that don't raise my status would just make me angry.

Is there a difference, on the SkyMiles Platinum card, between MQMs and 'bonus miles'?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Medallion Qualification Miles refers to the miles required to obtain/keep status.

The 'Bonus Miles' are simply standard miles, which can be used to book "free" flights, but which do NOT count towards your status.

Simple as that, really...

Comment: This answer is completely correct, but I just thought I'd point out that you can't actually spend the MQMs on flights, in case that isn't clear to anyone who may be reading. Only the 'bonus miles' count towards your SkyMiles balance that can be used for award tickets. As their name implies, MQMs are used solely for qualifying for Medallion (elite) status.